# Need to define output functions from logic circuit

Tags: circuits, digital-circuits

i was given a this circuit as exam question
[image]

So we need to define functions g and f. I defined them as $g(x,y,z) = x \oplus y \oplus z$ and  $f(x,y,z) = (x \oplus y) \cdot z$. By definition known that $S=A \oplus B \oplus C_{in}$ and $C_{out}=A\cdot B + (A\oplus B)\cdot C_{in}$;

$S_{FA(top,\ left)}=x \oplus y \oplus 0 = x \oplus y$ and $C_{out_{FA(top,\ right)}} = z\cdot 1 
+ (...)\cdot 0 = z$ then we have $S_{FA(bottom)}=x \oplus y \oplus 0 \oplus z = x \oplus y \oplus z = g $ and $C_{out_{FA(bottom)}} = (...)\cdot 0 + (x \oplus y \oplus 0) \cdot z =  (x \oplus y) \cdot z = f$

But my lecturer said, this is the wrong answer and didn't give me 25 points in an exam!
Truth table which i prepared:

[image]

It looks like the right answer to me. I tried to dispute the answer but my lecturer said: I don't see any reasons to change your grade.

Comment: You can ask your lecturer for the right answer.

Comment: I saw exam from one of the students , and he 
got full points for $f=(x+y)\cdot z$    $\ \ \ \ g=(x+y)+z$

Comment: I just need a hint where I was wrong.

Comment: I'd get *the other functions* **if** $C_{out}$ from top left was fed to "the output FA" as the middle input instead of "0".